# How to findall expressions to a word in kotlin?

Tags: android, list, android-studio, kotlin, findall

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val text = " \"id\": \"5jaq2\", \"mood\"  \"id\": \"RKlvj\", \"is_verified\"  \"id\": \"XPyZj\", \"mood\""
    val regex = Regex("id\": (.*?)[,]")
    val matches = regex.findAll(text)
    val names = matches.map { it.groupValues[1] }.toList()
    println(names)
}
```

I want to find all the id's but if  "is_verified" is after id, I dont want to put it in a list.

Current result:
["5jaq2", "RKlvj", "XPyZj"]

Expected:
["5jaq2", "XPyZj"]

Any idea how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
val regex = Regex("(?:\"id\":\\s)([\"\\w\\d]*?)(?:,\\s)(?!\"is_verified\")")
```

Explanation:

```
(?:\"id\":\\s)      // Non-capturing group to match {"id": }
([\"\\w\\d]*?)      // Capturing group to catch only words, digits and quotation marks characters
(?:,\\s)            // Non-capturing group to match {, }
(?!\"is_verified\") // Negative lookahead to not match if the next letters are {"is_verified"}
```

Tests: https://regexr.com/6inod

Comment: Hey thx, some weird stuff happens tho: https://pl.kotl.in/vj6CVJppj

Comment: @Skyline you are right, sorry for my mistake,. I fixed the Regex, now it is right with your test cases. But just pay attention because it is now just capturing the String if it has only words, digits and quotation marks characters. You can check it at: https://pl.kotl.in/9ZDfaYMMT